# Get property (none object) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a recommends table which has `user_id` and `product_id` column and I'm trying to display mostly viewed products but I get an error

> Trying to get property of non-object from the view,

if I `dd($viewed)` it shows all the products correctly but the problem is it can't display products and throws an error, any idea on how to solve this?

`Controller`

```php
$viewed = Recommends::with('product')
   ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
   ->select('product_id')
   ->inRandomOrder()
   ->groupBy('product_id')
   ->orderby('product_id', 'DESC')
   ->take(8)
   ->get();
```

`Blade` file

```
@foreach($viewed as $view)
 <h1>USD: {{$view->product->price}}</h1>
 <h2>USD: {{$view->product->info}}</h2>
@endforeach
```

When I dd($viewed) I get this

```
   Collection {#357 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
  0 => Recommends {#369 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "recommends"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "product_id" => 39
  ]
  #original: array:1 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "product" => product {#387 ▼
      #searchable: array:1 [▶]
      #table: "products"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #fillable: array:7 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:11 [▶]
      #original: array:11 [▼
        "id" => 39
        "name" => "e"
        "price" => 3
        "info" => "s"
```

Product.php

```
 public function recommends()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recommends','product_id');
}
```

Recommends.php

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the data returned when you do `dd()`

Comment: Maybe not all views have products? If so, you need to check if the product exists before you can get the property.

Comment: I have edited the question @codervine

Comment: Can you show your View model? It looks like products() might be `hasMany`, in which case you need to either get the first product, or add another loop

Comment: I have added the models @aynber

Comment: Could you edit the question and paste the complete error message you get?

Comment: It is weird that the related model is called `Product` (in uppercase) but in the dd the relationship appears `product` (in lower case). I tried it for the doubts and in the relations the class name appears to me as it is, not in lower case

Comment: Yeah because it takes this `public function product()` it is in lower case @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: I mean the class name, not the relationship name... not this one -> `"product" => product` <- this one should be Product,( i think)

Comment: Do you think this might be the problem ? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: I don't know, it's just an observation of something that seems strange to me, because when I do a dd, it shows me the name of the class in that place. If you look at Recommends, you will see that it is `Recommends` and  not `recommends`

Comment: try with $view->product['price']... etc..

Comment: I can't even see the product in view if i dd($viewed) the product is null `product" => null` but in controller is fine but can't pass to the view @pcalkins

Comment: so, show us how are you returning the view with the variable, i mean the return of your controller method

Comment: I return the view like  this `return view('front.home', compact('viewed','recommends'));` @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a collection of  **Recommends** objects which include the **Product** model.  The error is likely coming from a missing `product` on the `$view` variable.  Possibly due to the `GroupBy` statement or you may just not have a product attached to that View model.

Try this on your blade page to test:

```
<h1>USD: {{isset($view->product_id)?$view->product->price: 'No Product Set'}}</h1>
<h2>USD: {{isset($view->product_id)?$view->product->info: 'No Product Set'}}</h2>
```

Comment: I still get `Trying to get property of non-object` @Watercayman

Comment: OK, take out `->groupBy('product_id')
   ->orderby('product_id', 'DESC')` and try again please?  This is setting those fields to the Collection rather than each `view` model.

Comment: I have tried to take them out but still is not working  @Watercayman

Comment: OK, last thing to check: take out the `->select('product_id')` as well from the query (also the groupby and orderby).  Sometimes not having the whole model can change the query for the relationship.  Please try this as a diagnotic.  Oh, and the `->inRandomOrder()`.  Just make it simple to bug check

Comment: If the simplest version of the query isn't working, I'm a bit out of answers.  You've got it down to the bare bones.  May be something else above the `<h1>` lines.  Wait - how can you get a non-object error after checking isset in the blade?  Are you sure the error is on the `$view` var?

Comment: I'm not sure if the error is in the view or in controller because if I dd($views) I see products and everything @Watercayman

Comment: If you @dd($viewed) on the **blade** page do you get the same thing?  Correct collection including products?   Is the variable you are sending `$viewed` or `$views`?  Are you sending the right variable?

Comment: Well, there's the problem.  You are sending the wrong variable -- are you sending `$viewed` or `$views` from controller to blade?

Comment: Please post your view maker in your controller - if `$viewed` is showing correctly in controller and null in view, the problem is either the variable processing / name or how it is sent.  Please show the 'return view(...etc)' part of your controller

Comment: I return two variables in same view like this `return view('front.home', compact('viewed','recommends'));`. Even if I return like this `return view('front.home', compact('viewed'));` it still shows null in view @Watercayman

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  That code seems fine.  If `viewed` dumps fine from controller, and null from blade after what looks like a correct return statement, I don't know what to tell you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Do you think this might be  a cache or something ?@Watercayman

Answer (score 0):

**where you are passing $view in and where your loading view file
in your controller inside function try this:**

```
//controller
function abc(){
$viewed = Recommends::with('product')
   ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
   ->select('product_id')
   ->inRandomOrder()
   ->groupBy('product_id')
   ->orderby('product_id', 'DESC')
   ->take(8)
   ->get();
 return view('folder/blade_file_name', compact('viewed'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you attach the $viewed variable to view?
I think it is better to know how to debug this so i will try to help you that way.

Check if every $view variable has $product in the controller. some thing like this

```
    foreach($viewed as $view)
    {
        if (!$view->product) {
            dd($view);
        }
    }
```

if all the $viewed collection has product the problem is not in the data so we can move on on other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Having any relationship data/variable is empty then it will create error like same,so you will put condition like here.........

Blade file

```
  @if(!empty($viewed))
    @foreach($viewed as $view)
    <h1>USD: {{$view->product ? $view->product->price : ''}}</h1>
    <h2>USD: {{$view->product ? $view->product->info : ''}}</h2>
    @endforeach
  @endif
```